# Evernote Android-Job broadcast receiver not called

Tags: evernote, android-job

I am using Evernote Android-Job library to schedule jobs.

In their documentation they state that the JobManager needs to be instantiated in the onCreate of the Application and they provide a workaround in case that's not possible [relevant documentation section](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/FAQ.md#i-cannot-override-the-application-class-how-can-i-add-my-jobcreator)

The problem that I am facing is that method addJobCreator of the Broadcast receiver is never called even though the broadcast receiver is in the manifest. And ironically the only time I can get this method to be called is when i use `JobManager.create(this)` where `this` is an Activity context.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually expected and works properly. The broadcast receiver needs to be called before any job can run. The library may call `JobManager.create()` for you and then call your receiver. That's early enough so that you can add your `JobCreator`.

Comment: At what point does it happen? Should I explicitly call JobManager.create()?